# How do I expose the actual value of a Document Library custom column based on People and Groups in SharePoint 2013?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-workflow

SharePoint 2013 in Office 365

I have added a custom column to a Document Library.  The column is called "Author", and it is a lookup of type People and Group, filtered to show People only, and shows the field **Name**.

I have a workflow that is conditional upon the column being non-empty, but the Workflow builder doesn't have *is empty* or *is not empty* for that Current Item.FieldFromSource (Current Item:Author), so I've read the value into a string variable

[image]

Now I can check for existence:

[image]

However, I found that the behaviour of the Workflow was somewhat inconsistent, and as you probably know if you've read this far, Workflows are notoriously difficult to debug.  So, I created a Task that would run after the loop, assigned to the CurrentUser, that would show the value of the two data items (this in the Task Description):

```
Value of author = [%Variable: Author_Value%]
Other author = [%Current Item:Author%]
```

When I run the Workflow (having set the Author to Joe Bloggs) and examine the Task, instead of the author's name it has more-or-less gibberish.

[image]

Two questions -

1 - how can I output the Name of the Author, since that's what I thought I'd done?
2 - why is there not an *is empty / is not empty* for lookups? All of them, no matter what they are bound to, only seem to expose *equals / not equals*.

Thanks, and hope this makes sense!

Edward

Answer (score 0):

Just discovered that outputting the Current Item:Author as string is the issue - I've changed this to Display Names, Semicolon Delimited and it all works fine.  I still don't understand why the condition builder on lookup columns doesn't give you more than equals / not equals but hey ho, this is SharePoint.